# Bash script eval output and grep the substring of the output to write conditions

Tags: arrays, linux, mongodb, bash, replicaset

I have a command in variable `cmds`.

Upon executing this command on bash script `$eval ${cmds[1]}`, it has the output:

```
about to fork child process//
forked process: 1234
all output going to: /rand/direc/filename.log
child process started successfully, parent exiting.
```

I want to write a condition in bash where I look for "child process started successfully", and do certain commands,

`else echo -e "child process not started successfully"`

Comment: if grep -q "child process started successfully" <<< ${cmds[1]};then ....

Comment: @RamanSailopal I think your code checks if the output consists of "child process started successfully" and then executes the command ${cmds[1]}. right?

Comment: Is that not what you need?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Sorry if I wasn't clear before. Right now in my script, when i write $eval ${cmds[1]} i have the output "....child process not started successfully...". And I want to be able to read whether the output has that substring "child process not started successfully". If yes, then echo "good to go", else "not started".

Comment: @RamanSailopal any help?

Comment: if $eval ${cmds[1]} | grep -q "child process started successfully";then ....

Comment: @RamanSailopal It works but how do I also echo the output of  $eval ${cmds[1]}?

Answer (score 3):

Grep the execution of the command for the string piping through to tee /dev/tty to display the output of the command to screen

```
if eval ${cmds[1]} | tee /dev/tty | grep -q "child process not started successfully"
then 
     echo "OK"
fi
```